# Address and email in article class

Tags: article, addresses

How can I typeset email and address at the end of text (after References) in the `article` class just like in the `amsart` class? Does anyone know a macro for doing this?

Comment: If I am not wrong the `article` class does not offer this option.

Comment: Is there a macro for this work?

Comment: You can just write that stuff down!? Do you need something special?

Comment: it would not be easy to patch that into the `article` class.  a poor substitute is to just omit this information from the top matter (i.e., don't input it with the authors), and enter it as ordinary text (you'll have to do the "styling" yourself) after the references and before `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 18):

In the article class you can use the package `authblk`and the command `\affil`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\title{An important paper}

\author[$\dagger$]{R. Campbell}
\author[$\star$]{M. Dane}
\author[$\ddag$]{J. Jones}

\affil[$\dagger$]{Department of Mathematics, Pennsylvania State University,Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania 13593}
\affil[$\star$]{Atmospheric Research Station,
Pala Lundi, Fiji}
\affil[$\ddag$]{Department of Philosophy, Freedman College,
Periwinkle, Colorado 84320}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're not writing a new class, but just a document, the easiest way is to define a macro at the beginning and use it at the end; or just type the information where the example has `\Addresses`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\title{An important paper}

\author{R. Campbell
  \and
  M. Dane
  \and
  J. Jones
}

\newcommand{\Addresses}{{% additional braces for segregating \footnotesize
  \bigskip
  \footnotesize

  R.~Campbell, \textsc{Department of Mathematics, Pennsylvania State University,
    Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania 13593}\par\nopagebreak
  \textit{E-mail address}, R.~Campbell: \texttt{campr@galois.psu.edu}

  \medskip

  M.~Dane (Corresponding author), \textsc{Atmospheric Research Station,
    Pala Lundi, Fiji}\par\nopagebreak
  \textit{E-mail address}, M.~Dane: \texttt{DaneMark@@ffr.choice}

  \medskip

  J.~Jones, \textsc{Department of Philosophy, Freedman College,
    Periwinkle, Colorado 84320}\par\nopagebreak
  \textit{E-mail address}, J.~Jones: \texttt{id739e@@oseoi44 (Bitnet)}

}}

\maketitle

\lipsum

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A} A. Uthor, A paper, J. of Interesting Results, 2015

\end{thebibliography}

\Addresses

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to the [AMS LaTeX class documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/amsclass.pdf):

> In an article, typesetting of the address information is done at the end of the
>   document, by calling `\@setaddresses`. This is done through a parent function
>   `\enddoc@text`, because some AMS journals also print the abstract there instead
>   of at the beginning, and it's easier to redefine `\enddoc@text` than to try undoing
>   material already added to the `\AtEndDocument` hook.

The following `amsart` minimal document

```
\documentclass{amsart}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amslatex

% Taken from the AMS LaTeX class documentation
\author{Roland Campbell}
\address{Department of Mathematics\\
  Pennsylvania State University\\
  Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania 13593}
\email[R.~Campbell]{campr@@galois.psu.edu}
\author{Mark M. Dane}
  % Same address as R. Campbell
\curraddr[M.~Dane]{Atmospheric Research Station\\
  Pala Lundi, Fiji}
\email[M.~Dane]{DaneMark@@ffr.choice}
\author{Jeremiah Jones}
\address[J.~Jones]{Department of Philosophy\\
  Freedman College\\
  Periwinkle, Colorado 84320}
\email[J.~Jones]{id739e@@oseoi44 (Bitnet)}

\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

produces at the end of the document

[image]

My suggestion would be to emulate the title properties (author, email, address, ...) using the `\AtEndDocument` hook, since its use is singular:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry

\AtEndDocument{\bigskip{\footnotesize%
  \textsc{Department of Mathematics, Pennsylvania State University, Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania 13593} \par  
  \textit{E-mail address}, R.~Campbell: \texttt{campr@galois.psu.edu} \par
  \addvspace{\medskipamount}
  \textit{Current address}, M.~Dane: Atmospheric Research Station, Pala Lundi, Fiji \par
  \textit{E-mail address}, M.~Dane: \texttt{DaneMark@@ffr.choice} \par
  \addvspace{\medskipamount}
  (J.~Jones) \textsc{Department of Philosophy, Freedman College, Periwinkle, Colorado 84320} \par
  \textit{E-mail address}, J.~Jones: \texttt{id739e@@oseoi44 (Bitnet)}
}}

\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you want to use `\AtEndDocument`: some packages may add code to it, and your code would be executed *later*. Think to `lastpage`, for instance.