# Compilation error: Argument of \put has an extra }

Tags: compiling, compilation-error

I recently installed the latest version of MacTex, and whenever I try to compile any of my files which uses the tikz package I get the following error:

Argument of `\put` has an extra `}`

I have tried adding `\let\put\latexput` and `let\latexput\put` as suggested by the answer to the question [Previously working code now gives "Argument of \put has an extra }" after TeXLive/MiKTeX reinstall](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574592/previously-working-code-now-gives-argument-of-put-has-an-extra-after-texliv) , but neither of these solves my problem.

Here is my code:

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true,colorlinks]{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,amsrefs,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\usepackage{mathpazo} % add possibly `sc` and `osf` options
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{lscape}%puts selected page in landscape mode
\usepackage{etex} %allows xRightarrow
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%This is used to add colors to rows and columns in arrays (which I use for matrices) WARNING: Must load before tikz packages (i believe arrows.meta uses xcolor so there is a clash). or another option is to add "table" as a global option to the document class, ex. \documentclass[12pt,table]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}%Used for reallywidehat
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{xfrac}%use commands such as \sfrac{1}{2}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{dsfont}%this is for mathbb{1} but you write mathds{1}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}%this forces footnotes to appear on the bottom of page
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subfig} %this is to plot figures vertically
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pictexwd, dcpic}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[all]{xy} %This is to make higher categorical stuff
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,%set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,%set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=blue,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
    citecolor=blue,
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%to reduce spacing of titles in table of contents%%%%
%%%%%found this at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396795/how-to-reduce-spacing-between-chapters-in-table-of-content%%%%%%
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  beforeskip=-0.3em plus 1pt,% default is 1em plus 1pt
  pagenumberformat=\textbf
]{tocline}{section}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%shift horizontal spacing to allow overlay from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51113/horizontal-equivalent-to-raisebox




%%%%%FROM CHO--JACOBS
\input{tikzdefs}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%Title and Author%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Quantum Computing for the Masses}
\author{James Fullwood}
%\date{\today}

%egreg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150841/address-and-email-in-article-class
\newcommand{\Addresses}{{% additional braces for segregating \footnotesize
  \bigskip
  \footnotesize


\begin{document}
\emergencystretch 2em

\maketitle
%\begin{abstract}  
%\end{abstract}

\vspace{-7mm}
\tableofcontents


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Classical vs. Quantum Information}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you provide the **code** (one example) plus the **log file** that produces the error, please refer to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner how to add the log file?

Comment: Copy and paste the content of the file with the extension .log

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I tried this but the log file had way too many characters, and I am not sure which part is relevant.

Comment: you will have to show your code. Without a small, complete example we can't test that.

Comment: Look at the link that I provided in my first comment. This will make the log file shorter.